# In Postgresql, after grouping, return false if any value of a column is false. If all values are true/false, then return true/false respectively

Tags: postgresql, boolean, grouping, logical-operators, logical-and

I have a table called 'apple' and I wrote the following query:

```
select name, 
       count(name), 
       case when istasty is null then false else istasty end 
from apple 
group by name, istasty;
```

This the output:

[image]

I am trying to group the `name` and `istasty` flag using following condition:

1. When the corresponding name column has both true or false, then I return false. In the above image, `tala` has both `true` and `false` `istasty` column. However, I want to return false because it has atleast one false `istasty` column.
2. If after grouping all `istasty` column for a particular name column is `true` then return `true`; Similarly, if all `istasty` column is `false`, then return `false` for that particular name column.

I can achieve using the `bool_and` operator in `postgresql` by writing the query:

```
select name, count(name), bool_and(coalesce(istasty = true, false)) from apple group by name;
```

[image]

Is there any way I can modify my first query so that I add filter in `having clause` to achieve the same result as I got using `bool_and` operator in second query? Or is there any other possible way?

Please note I am not using `bool_and` operator. I appreciate your time. Thank you.

Comment: Unrelated, but: `coalesce(istasty = true, false)` is the same as `coalesce(istasty, false)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An alternative to using the `bool_and` operator would be regular conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    name,
    COUNT(*) AS count,
    CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN !istasty THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
         THEN FALSE ELSE TRUE END AS result
FROM apple
GROUP BY name;
```

I am not sure what you have in mind when you suggest using the `HAVING` clause.  By moving the conditional check to the `HAVING` clause you may exclude/include specific groups in the query matching the condition.

Comment: Thank you. Small comment : Instead of !isTasty Postgresql accepts ' WHEN istasty IS FALSE..

Answer (score 0):

Your logic (return true only if all values are true) equates to getting the `min()` boolean value:

```
select
    name,
    min(istasty::varchar(5))::boolean
from (select name, case when istasty is null then false else istasty end istasty
      from apple
      group by name, istasty) x
group by name
```

Note that postgres doesn't support aggregating `boolean` values, so you have to cast to character then back to boolean to use `min()`.

Comment: You can aggregate booleans using `bool_and()` and `bool_or()`